# docker attach doesn't attach to the container

Tags: docker

I ran a docker container on one of the terminals, on the other terminal:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
80b6be3a7d56   rbonghi/isaac-ros-tutorial:realsense-camera   "/ros_entrypoint.sh …"   9 seconds ago   Up 8 seconds             inspiring_almeida
```

and then I run

```
$ docker attach inspiring_almeida
```

now nothing seems to happen, cursor moves to a new line.

```
$ docker attach inspiring_almeida
```

What am I doing wrong? I expected to see something like `root@80b6be3a7d56`

P.s. I'm accessing the machine that I run docker via SSH - if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Run `docker exec -it inspiring_almeida /bin/bash`. It runs a shell inside the container.

`attach` just connects your input/output terminal with the container's input/output.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I cannot accept it since my reputation is <50.